# Is unconstrained integer convex optimization problem NP-hard?

Tags: convex-optimization, computational-complexity, oc.optimization-and-control

Does anyone know a reference to the answer if unconstrained integer convex optimization problem (i.e. $\min_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^N} F(x)$, $F$ is convex and $N$ is NOT fixed) is NP-hard?

Thank you in advance.

Well, thanks to your critical comments I've found the answer to the question, and here it is.
Let $F$ be a piecewise linear convex function, i.e. $F(x)=\max_{j\in J} \sum_{i=1}^N a_i^j x_i + a_0^j$, then $\min_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^N} F(x) = \min_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^N} \max_{j\in J}\{\sum_{i=1}^N a_i^j x_i + a_0^j\} = \min_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^N} \min_{f\in \mathbb{R}} (f, s.t. f\geq \sum_{i=1}^N a_i^j x_i + a_0^j, \forall j\in J)$, the last optimization problem is a mixed integer linear program, which is known to be NP-Hard.

Comment: What is the input of the problem, and what is $F$?

Comment: F is an arbitrary convex function, doesn't have to be smooth. I guess the only input is F, but I'm interested in a general result for any convex F.

Comment: First, a function from where to where? Second, the input of a computational problem is a finite string in a finite alphabet. How do you represent your function in such a way?

Comment: F:Z^N -> R and assume there is a oracle giving the value of F(x) for each integral x.

Comment: This is making less and less sense. NP is a class of unrelativized problems, it is meaningless to compare it with problems depending on an oracle. Even worse, if the function is provided by an oracle, then the problem has *no* input at all! In such a setting, no concepts involving complexity measures based on the length of the input (such as polynomial-time reductions, NP, etc) make any sense.

Comment: oops, the only input is N

Comment: How can $F$ be fixed, if $N$ is varying, if the domain of $F$ is supposed to be $\mathbb{Z}^N$? 

Comment: The question needs to be rewritten so that it unambiguously defines the computational model being used and what is meant by “NP-hard” in this context, in sufficient detail so that it becomes a well-defined problem, rather than a vague metaphor. Until then I’m voting to close as not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the shortest vector in lattice problem is NP-hard, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem